# Is there a way to get the type of an inherited generic class using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this as my class signature:

```
public class LocationRule : IRule<Location>
```

I am trying to use `reflection` to access the type of the implementation of `IRule`.

Using this code

```
Assembly.GetTypes()
  .Where(type => typeof(IRule<Location>).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
    && !type.IsInterface)
```

I can get the classes that inherit this specific implementation of `IRule`. However there is no way to dynamically insert a type into this `expression` like so.

```
Assembly.GetTypes()
  .Where(type => typeof(IRule<typeof(AnotherClass)>).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
    && !type.IsInterface)
```

Is there away to find all classes that implement `IRule<>` and then find out all the types that are implemented?

```
public class LocationRule : IRule<Location>
public class NameRule : IRule<Name>
```

Is there a way to get hold of each of these types? Name and Location, so I can place them in a `Dictionary<TypeOfIRuleGeneric, TypeOfRuleClass>` i.e Key = Location, Value = LocationRule?

Thanks.

Comment: `However there is no way to dynamically insert a type` - you can do that using `Type.MakeGenericType()`

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for some kind of "commonality" between all `IRule<T>` types. You could define a base interface as dcg suggested, but that won't lead into the second part of your question where you want to pull out the generic type parameters and insert them into a dictionary.

There is a thing called a *generic type definition* that represents a "stripped-down" generic type, with all of the generic type parameters removed. You can use this as the "commonality" instead.

```
typeof(IRule<Location>).GetGenericTypeDefinition() // MyApp.IRule`1[T]
```

But C# lets you actually use an unspecified generic type within `typeof` to give you the same thing more succinctly:

```
typeof(IRule<>) // compiles! Also gives MyApp.IRule`1[T]
```

`IsAssignableFrom` won't be useful here because you cannot instantiate an unconstructed generic type to begin with.

I made a helper method that gets all generic interfaces implemented by a type:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetGenericInterfaces(this Type type)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces().Where(t => t.IsGenericType);
}
```

Here's another method that tells me whether I can construct a type from a given generic type definition:

```
public static bool IsConstructableFrom(this Type type, Type genericTypeDefinition)
{
    return type.IsConstructedGenericType &&
        (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericTypeDefinition);
}
```

Now your query would be:

```
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type =>
        !type.IsInterface &&
        type.GetGenericInterfaces().Any(generic => generic.IsConstructableFrom(typeof(IRule<>))))
    .ToArray();
```

But ultimately you want a `Dictionary<TypeOfIRuleGeneric, TypeOfRuleClass>`, where the key is the generic type parameter of `IRule<>` and the value is the class that implements it. I am going to assume that you'll have at most one class that implements `IRule<T>` for a particular `T` (is this assumption true?). I'll also assume that each class will implement at most one `IRule<T>` (is this assumption true?).

There's a lot of ways to do that part. I came up with this:

```
var dict = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => !type.IsInterface)
    .Select(type => new
    {
        TypeOfRuleClass = type,
        IRuleInterface = type
            .GetGenericInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(generic => generic.IsConstructableFrom(typeof(IRule<>)))
    })
    .Where(t => t.IRuleInterface != null)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.TypeOfRuleClass, t => t.IRuleInterface.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
```

- The first `Where` filters out interfaces from the candidate types
- The `Select` transforms each candidate type into a tuple `(TypeOfRuleClass, IRuleInterface)` where `IRuleInterface` is the first (and only, by assumption) matching `IRule<T>` type implemented by `TypeOfRuleClass`; or, it's `null` if the type does not implement `IRule<T>`
- The second `Where` filters out candidate types that do not implement `IRule<T>`
- The `ToDictionary` creates the dictionary you wanted, where the key is `TypeOfRuleClass` and the value is the generic type parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the detail that's very helpful, I need to check it in my code and see but I think this might be the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all types that implements a specific interface you can do it like the following:

```
public interface IMyInterface { }

public class MyClass: IMyInterface { }

//...
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => !t.IsInterface && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IMyInterface)))
    .ToList();
```

Here `types` would be populated with `MyClass`.

Comment: Thank you, I can get all the types, but I'm looking to access the Type within the generic parameters <Type> since it is difference for each class that inherits it!